# Friend function massacred by circular includes

Tags: c++, include, friend, circular-dependency

Class `A` is the sole instantiator and container of instances of class `B`.

So it seemed like a good idea to make the constructor of class `B` private, and call it only by a friend function declared in class `B` and defined in class `A`.

**File A.h** (EDIT: included enum defined in class B)

```
#ifndef   A_H
#define   A_H

#include "B.h"

using namespace std;

class A
{   public:
    A();
    shared_ptr<B> CreateBInstance( const B::ENUM_STANDARD_COLORS );
    shared_ptr<B> CreateBInstance( const string );  // Custom color

    private:
    unique_ptr<map<int, shared_ptr<B>>> UPTR__BInstancesMap;
}
#endif
```

**File B.h** (EDIT: included enum defined in class B)

```
#ifndef   B_H
#define   B_H

#include "A.h"  // Causes chaos

using namespace std;

class B
{   public:
    enum class ENUM_STANDARD_COLORS : unsigned int
    {   ...     // ~70 standard colors
    };

    private:
    B();

    friend
    shared_ptr<B> A::CreateBInstance( const ENUM_STANDARD_COLORS );

    friend
    shared_ptr<B> A::CreateBInstance( const string );   // Custom color
}
#endif
```

Class `A` requires a full declaration (#include) of class `B` for `shared_ptr<B>`.

Class `B` requires some declaration of class `A` for the friend function.
A simple forward declaration causes the error:

> invalid use of incomplete type 'struc A'

at the friend function declaration.

A full declaration (#include) is far worse:

> error: prototype for 'std::shared_ptr A::CreateInstance()' does not
>   match any in class 'A'

(but it does!) at the friend function declaration.
And, because class `B` is now broken:

> error: 'B' was not declared in this scope
> error: template argument 1 is invalid

appears at every mention of `B` in class `A`, as well as in classes `F` and `G` (etc.) which #include class `B` for their own use of `shared_ptr<B>`.
And, because classes `F` and `G` are also now broken:

> error: 'F' was not declared in this scope
> error: template argument 1 is invalid>
> error: 'G' was not declared in this scope
> error: template argument 1 is invalid

appears at every mention of `F` and `G` in class `A`.

Unfortunately, the include guards don't prevent the circular inclusion.

Is there a way to make this friend function work?  I've never achieved so many errors in one go!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Class `A` requires a full declaration (#include) of class `B` for `shared_ptr<B>`.

No, forward declaration would be sufficient in `A.h`. [`shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) (and [`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)) won't require class `B` to be complete type for return type declaration<sup>[1]</sup> and class data member declaration.

File A.h

```
#ifndef   A_H
#define   A_H

class B;  // forward declaration

using namespace std;

class A
{   public:
    A();
    shared_ptr<B> CreateBInstance();

    private:
    unique_ptr<map<int, shared_ptr<B>>> UPTR__BInstancesMap;
};
#endif
```

---

<sup>[1] It's also true for "regular" type `T` which isn't `shared_ptr`.</sup>

Comment: When I replace "#include B.h" with "class B;" the compiler gives me "invalid use of incomplete type 'struc B' throughout A.cpp.  I believe I read that pointers require a full definition in order to support function calls (e.g. sptr__BInstance01->print();)

Comment: @pbyhistorian You should `#include B.h` in `A.cpp`, just don't do it in `A.h`.

Comment: Ah, I've used that before, successfully.  The problem in this case is that a function declaration in class A has a parameter whose type is defined by a public enum in class B.  I think the trick may be to use forward references in all of the other headers (F.h, G.h) and use includes in all of the other cpp files.  Then I should be able to use includes safely in A.  I'll try that tomorrow morning.

Comment: @pbyhistorian Seems you have to include `B.h` in `A.h`, which leads to circular-dependency issue. Better to reconsider about the design, like move the public enum type out of class `B`.

Comment: I think it's even worse than that.  I #include B.h through G.h in A.h, I #include B.h in F.h and G.h, and I #include G.h in F.h.  All this cross-including (and there's more) can't be good.  I think your answer will let me reduce the header includes to just one.

Comment: After sleeping on it, I believe, as you say, the answer is ultimately "no" without falsifying class B for the sake of a friend function.  I'll leave the question open for a few days in case someone knows an obscure loophole.

Comment: @pbyhistorian One of the obscure loopholes, is to make it a friend class declaration, like `friend class A;` in `B.h`. Then no need to include `A.h` in `B.h`. But it will make all the member functions of class `A` friend of `B`, might be a bad idea.

Comment: Agreed.  I think even a friend function gives too much access.  I think I'd rather have no friends :)

Comment: @pbyhistorian You can also make `A` inner class of `B` to avoid friend declaration and all these including issue.

Comment: I did consider that (from my Java experience), but I thought a stack of inner, inner-inner, and even inner-inner-inner classes would get ugly fast.  In the end, friend classes didn't seem so bad.

Answer (score 2):

In A header file, you can simply tell the compiler that an type B exists and it needs to look for it while linking. To do so, replace

```
#include "B.h"
```

by

```
class B;
```

Answer (score 0):

Making class A a friend of class B eliminated the circular include (as described in the comments under songyuanyao's answer above) but I don't like giving A so much access to B.

I think I've come up with a better approach, using inheritance.  If this friend-limited-by-inheritance factory pattern has a name, it would be nice to know.  Otherwise it would be nice to know if I'm playing with fire here.

**File A.h**

```
#ifndef   A_H
#define   A_H

#include "B.h"          // The more compelling reason for including B.h is that
                        // classes A thru Z comprise a static library, requiring
                        // only the inclusion of A.h to be used.  B.h through Z.h
                        // must be included directly or indirectly in A.h so that
                        // the caller knows all of the library's public functions.

using namespace std     // Makes these examples easier to read.

class A
{   public:
    A();
    shared_ptr<B> CreateBInstance( const B::ENUM_STANDARD_COLORS );
    shared_ptr<B> CreateBInstance( const string );  // Custom color

    private:
//  Please excuse my standards-defying variable names
    unique_ptr<map<int, shared_ptr<B>>> UPTR__BInstancesMap;
}
#endif
```

**File A.cpp**

```
#include   "A.h"
#include   "BFactory.h"

...
    shared_ptr<B> A::CreateBInstance( const B::ENUM_STANDARD_COLORS enum__StandardColor )
    {   unsigned int  uint__BInstancesMapIndex = UPTR__BInstancesMap->size();
        shared_ptr<B> sptr__BInstance          = BFactory::CreateBInstance( uint__BInstancesMapIndex, enum__StandardColor );
        UPTR__BInstancesMap->insert( uint__BInstancesMapIndex, sptr__BInstance );
        return sptr__BInstance;
    }

    shared_ptr<B> A::CreateBInstance( const string str___CustomColor )
    {   unsigned int  uint__BInstancesMapIndex = UPTR__BInstancesMap->size();
        shared_ptr<B> sptr__BInstance          = BFactory::CreateBInstance( uint__BInstancesMapIndex, str___CustomColor   );
        UPTR__BInstancesMap->insert( uint__BInstancesMapIndex, sptr__BInstance );
        return sptr__BInstance;
    }
...
```

**File B.h**

```
#ifndef   B_H
#define   B_H

using namespace std             // Makes these examples easier to read.

class B
{   public:
    enum class ENUM_STANDARD_COLORS : unsigned int
    {   ...                     // ~70 standard colors
    };

//  virtual                     // BFactory cannot be instantiated; it needs no destructor
    ~B();

    protected:
    static unique_ptr<B> CreateBInstance( const unsigned int, const ENUM_STANDARD_COLORS );
    static unique_ptr<B> CreateBInstance( const unsigned int, const string );   // Custom color

    private:
    B( const unsigned int );    // Eliminates default constructor, therefore BFactory cannot
                                // call B::B(); therefore the compiler does not generate
                                // BFactory::BFactory(); therefore BFactory (and BFactory.o)
                                // is empty; it doesn't even need a cpp file.
}
#endif
```

**File B.cpp**

```
#include "B.h"
...
   unique_ptr<B> B::CreateBInstance( const unsigned int uint__BInstancesMapIndex, const ENUM_STANDARD_COLORS enum__StandardColor )
   {   unique_ptr<B> uptr__BInstance = unique_ptr<B>( new B( uint__BInstancesMapIndex ) );
       uptr__BInstance->SetColor( enum__StandardColor );
       return uptr__BInstance;
   }

   unique_ptr<B> B::CreateBInstance( const unsigned int uint__BInstancesMapIndex, const string               str___CustomColor   )
   {   unique_ptr<B> uptr__BInstance = unique_ptr<B>( new B( uint__BInstancesMapIndex ) );
       uptr__BInstance->SetColor( str___CustomColor   );
       return uptr_BInstance;
   }
...
```

**File BFactory.h**

```
#ifndef   BFactory_H
#define   BFactory_H

#include  "B.h"

class BFactory : private B          // Make sure anything inherited from B becomes private.
{   friend class A                  // Friend declaration moved from class B.
};

#endif
```

Summary of changes:
1) Class A is no longer a friend of class B.
2) Class B's factory functions are made protected so BFactory will inherit them, and made static so that we don't need an instance of BFactory to call them.
3) Class BFactory is an empty subclass of B with no constructors, destructor, or local members; it merely inherits B's factory functions and declares class A as a friend.
4) Class A now calls static functions in BFactory to obtain instances of B rather than calling private functions in B.

The result is that only Class A can access the static factory functions of class B, and class BFactory cannot be used for anything else - as far as I can tell.